# Tags Sorted By Characters?

Tags: tags, template-tags

If i put multiple tags in a post then after publishing the post all tags are auto arranged by Character Serial, like A B C D... any idea if i wish to have all tags will not sorted or arranged by Character serial.... so, first tag will be first and last tag will be placed at last... though the first tag may be start with Z and the last tag start with A .. So what is the way to keep tag serial static as i have put?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wp_get_post_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) to achieve this. The third argument for this function supports an `orderby` parameter which defaults to name i.e. to sort alphabetically by name

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all');
// orderby also supports 'count', 'slug', 'term_group', 'term_order', and 'term_id'
```

The first 2 arguments of that function may be left as default

Comment: thanks for your reply .. so where i should edit the code?

Comment: In your template files, where the tags are being displayed.

Comment: is that tag.php ?

Comment: no, the file responsible for the output where you're seeing the posts & their tags. This totally depends on the theme